# generating primary key in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, uuid

I would like to possibly use GENERATE_UUID() to create a primary key, but only against certain compound keys (columns) of the table, and not from the data of whole row, is that possible?

Comment: GENERATE_UUID() function takes no parameters and generates random universally unique identifier (UUID) as a STRING. Has nothing to do with which columns you consider as compound keys. please clarify your use case. best way is to present example of what data you have and what you expect to ...

Comment: Yes, I would like to create a primary key using certain columns as compound keys.  I think what I'll do is I'll break the key creation step into another process (view) & join the original back to the new view w/ the UUID'd data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I'll do is I'll break the key creation step into another process (view) & join the original back to the new view w/ the UUID'd data.  Also, I'll use something like Farm fingerprint to create the uuid